# Scrollable div stops working on 3D rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with four containers shaped into a cube.  When you click the "Click Here" button, the pages rotate as expected, but you cannot scroll Page 2 or 4 once the animation has completed, only before it has completed, which is undesired.  The code I'm working with is below.  Any ideas on how to get all of the scrollable pages to work correctly?

The HTML:

```
<center><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</button></center>

<div class="cube-container">
    <div class="cube-card">
        <div class="container-main" id="Container-1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <br>Page 1<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-main" id="Container-2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <br>Page 2<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-main" id="Container-3">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <br>Page 3<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-main" id="Container-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <br>Page 4<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.cube-container {
    perspective: 320;
    perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
    transform: scale(1);
    margin-top: 25px;
}

div.cube-card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.container-main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background-color: #e0e4e5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

div.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

The JS:

```
var page = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        var halfWidth = $(window).width() / 2;

        $("div#Container-1").css({webkitTransform: "rotateY(0deg) translateZ(" + halfWidth + "px)"});
        $("div#Container-2").css({webkitTransform: "rotateY(90deg) translateZ(" + halfWidth + "px)"});
        $("div#Container-3").css({webkitTransform: "rotateY(180deg) translateZ(" + halfWidth + "px)"});
        $("div#Container-4").css({webkitTransform: "rotateY(270deg) translateZ(" + halfWidth + "px)"});
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
        page = page + 1;

        var angle = -((page * 90) - 90);

        if (page == 5) {
            page = 1;
        }

        if (angle == -360) {
            angle = 0;
        }

        $("div.cube-card").css({webkitTransition: "-webkit-transform 0.60s"});
        $("div.cube-card").css({webkitTransform: "rotateY(" + angle + "deg)"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  The perspective value was too small.  Tested setting it to 2000 and anything larger and it worked fine.

**UPDATE**

This broke on the release of iOS 8.  To get scroll to work on the second page (the one that's rotated 90 degrees), I had to remove "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"  At least it scrolls now, but it's extremely choppy.  Any idea on how to allow momentum scroll on this page again?